# preventing Date-picker from auto-select a date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datepicker

I am using and readonly datepicker (bootstrap) with disabled weekends and public holidays. When selecting a month/ year however it always selects the first day of the month or year and only moves on to the date selection if this first day is an invalid. The datepicker modal opens initially with the current day (which is also an invalid day ..on purpose) so it let me select an day but ones i go to month or even years before selecting a day of the current month, it populates it with the default of the first day of the month/year. is there a way to prevent this from happing and only updates the date ones day, month and year has been selected by the user.

Comment: It will be better if you can add a fiddle to demonstrate the problem

Comment: You can just temporarily store days, month and year separately. Only set the date of the datepicker once all 3 values are set.

Answer (score 0):

Use setDate method you can clear input field state this way:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#datepicker').val('').datepicker('update');
```

Or

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker('update', '');
```

[Source](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#update)